# How can I tell a github repository's quality?

Tags: github, open-source

Many a time do I find myself pointed out to use some code in some github repository, and I find it hard to asses whether I should trust and use the code.

Assuming The code is an answer to my visible needs, what other parameters should I check in order to decide if using the code is a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the chrome extension [DevGib](http://iic-ninjas.github.io/DevGib/) that I wrote. It automatically rates Stackoverflow questions and Github repositories before accessing them, by showing a small colored icon next to the link. It's still work in progress but it does the job for me.

Comment: Just to note the website and repo of the extension could not be found now. It's still present in the Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devgib/pkchajlcgibonmocadnippbgjkceieeb, but I don't think it's going to be updated.

Comment: The links were broken because the project moved a Github organization.
You can find the repo here: https://github.com/ShayDavidson/DevGib, and the Github page here: http://code-cats-coffee.com/DevGib/

While it's true the project hasn't been updated for a while, it's still working and used by daily basis by many people I know :).

Answer (score 2):

You should check:

- documentation - Is everything clearly documented? Would you need support from the author to use the code?
- activity - Sometimes authors could not constantly push updates to the library, but it is important issues and pull requests are resolved rather quickly. Common bugs often are resolved by others in a pull request, but if it's not merged it's rather hard to handle all the forks.

  Also you should check the Pulse page in the repo. It will show the activity in issues, commits and releases.
- extensibility - You may want to do something different with the library. Or you may want to build something on top of it. You should check the API (the public interface), the configuration and whether some components could be changed with something else (think interfaces and the composite design pattern).
- tests - Unit tests are important. You should write tests for your own application. When you use an external library, make sure it is well tested so you use a component which will work the same when you update it or use it in a different environment. If the code is not tested you should not use it. Unless you wrote the tests yourself.

Comment: Thanks HaralanDobrev, you gave me some nice pointers but @Indigon's chrome extension is the tool I was looking for.

Comment: @gardenofwine The extension would rate a repo based solely on [number of forks and watchers](https://github.com/iic-ninjas/DevGib/blob/b7cf842f5c715ad96b4e7b18580716466aca583f/src/coffee/background/sites/github.coffee#L19). These are not good enough measures! If a repo is not updated it could have many forks. If a good repo is very active it could still have a small number of watchers, because people don't want the noise. In overall these metrics only show the popularity of a repo, not its quality.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev you are right. Currently my extension ranks repository based on popularity, but sometimes popularity equals quality. Repository popularity might indicate that the code is maintained and improved constantly. Nevertheless, keep in mind that the extension is WIP and was released only recently, so there is room for improvement.

Comment: @Indigon If you want to measure popularity, count the stars. Also the number of contributors and open/closed issues could be useful. Cheers ;)

Comment: @HaralanDobrev It's on the todo list :)

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes here without a comment.